# Replacing every empty line with a string, i.e. inserting strings to empty lines

Tags: replace, regular-expressions

Given that I have a file such as

```
Lorem


Ipsum

Dolor
```

I want to insert strings (here, the % character) to those empty lines to obtain

```
Lorem
%
%
Ipsum
%
Dolor
```

How can I do this? I tried to follow a way similar to the methods defined [here](http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/removing-blank-lines-buffer) without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun filibuster (str)
  (interactive "sString: ")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "^$" nil t)
      (replace-match str))))
```

Comment: May I ask why you chose the name `filibuster` :)

Comment: It had to have fill in in. Close enough:)

Comment: hi abo, may i know why the whole logic is wrapped in a save-excursion? is it to preserve the current cursor position & resume it, after finishing the replacements...

Comment: @MadhavanKumar, yes.

Answer (score 2):

@abo-abo gave the Lisp answer. You don't specify whether you want to do this from Lisp or interactively. Interactively, you can do what you ask in either of these ways:

- `M-x replace-regexp RET ^$ RET % RET`
- `C-M-% RET ^$ RET % RET !`